# Convert from integer (decimal UTF-16 encoding) to character in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have a vector of integers that represent characters encoded as UTF-16 decimal. How do I convert the vector of integers into a UTF-8 string vector in R?

For example:

```
x <- c(75, 252, 110)

y <- <convert_function>(x)

y
> "K" "ü" "n"
```

where `<convert_function>()` is what I am after.

Comment: `unlist(strsplit(intToUtf8(x), ""))`Gives you `[1] "K" "ü" "n"`

Comment: Ah, I though that having chars in separate strings would have been easier, but I do need a single string after all, so the `intToUtf8(x)` would do.